# Example for calling a stored procedure in Oracle SQL from Java using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have seen examples for calling procedures where the return type is a number, by using `CallableStatement` and then setting the `IN` parameters and registering the `OUT` parameters based on the return type.

But how to do the same, if the `OUT` parameter is a table returned by a `SELECT` statement?

I have tried to find some examples but of no use. Please help.

This is some example code where the `OUT` parameter is an integer

```
  // Prepare to call the stored procedure RAISESAL.
  // This sample uses the SQL92 syntax
    CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall ("{? = call RAISESAL (?, ?)}");
  // Declare that the first ? is a return value of type Int
     cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, Types.INTEGER);

    // We want to raise LESLIE's salary by 20,000
    cstmt.setString (2, "LESLIE");  // The name argument is the second ?
    cstmt.setInt (3, 20000);        // The raise argument is the third ?

    // Do the raise
    cstmt.execute ();

    // Get the new salary back
    int new_salary = cstmt.getInt (1);

    System.out.println ("The new salary is: " + new_salary);
```

But I want an example where the `OUT` parameter is a table (`SYS_REFCURSOR`).

Comment: Where are your examples that you tried, especially the CallableStatement. Please share. Also give details of the problems you ran into - error messages etc.

Comment: I don't know how to register an OUT parameter, if it is of type SYS_REFCURSOR i.e., if it returns a table.

Comment: Are you trying to do anything like: https://www.boraji.com/jdbc-callablestatement-resultset-example. It cannot return a table, though it can return a resultset

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/

Comment: take a look here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28765/addfunc.htm#TDPJD206

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your first parameter as a REF_CURSOR

```
cstmt.registerOutParameter (1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Here is a complete example that uses JDBC-OCI but you can use JDBC-thin (in fact you should):
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a83724/samapp5.htm